# Installing R on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I have been trying to install R on Ubuntu 23.04 but have been getting the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libicu70 (>= 70.1-1~) but it is not installable
               Depends: libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install r-base`. By any chance did you add any external repositories for installing R?

Comment: Both `libicu70` and `libtiff5` were removed from Ubuntu after 22.04. Their presence in your error message strongly suggests that you are trying to install a wrong-version or non-Ubuntu package. Stop doing that. `r-base-core` is available in the Ubuntu 23.04 repositories, and does not have those dependencies.